# Fitting a canvas data to another canvas in paperjs

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to fit a `paperjs` canvas into another canvas. I am using `importJSON` to import the canvas into current paperjs canvas object. However, the sizes are different for the 2 canvases and therefore, not all content is visible. I tried to set the view of the paperjs project but that didn't work. This is what I tried:

```
canvasObj.project.importJSON(tabData.dataUrl);
canvasObj.project.view.viewSize = new paper.Size(window.innerWidth - this.canvasWidthSubtract, window.innerHeight - this.canvasHeightSubtract);
```

In this, I am first loading the canvas using `importJSON` and setting the view. However, not all the content is visible. How can fit the contents of importJSON to the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply resize the imported layer to fit the bounds of the [`View`](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#bounds) of your 2nd canvas.

You can easily do this with the [`item.fitBounds`](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#fitbounds-rectangle) method as illustrated below.

```
const imported = project.importJSON(`[["Layer",{"applyMatrix":true,"selected":true,"children":[["Path",{"applyMatrix":true,"selected":true,"segments":[[351.69873,371.5],[395,296.5],[438.30127,371.5]],"closed":true,"fillColor":[0.91373,0.91373,1]}],["Path",{"applyMatrix":true,"selected":true,"segments":[[479.54915,481.55283],[454.54915,463.38926],[445,434],[454.54915,404.61074],[479.54915,386.44717],[510.45085,386.44717],[535.45085,404.61074],[545,434],[535.45085,463.38926],[510.45085,481.55283]],"closed":true,"fillColor":[0.91373,0.91373,1]}]]}]]`)
const layer = imported.pop()

layer.fitBounds(view.bounds)
```

The example above imports a JSON exported via [`project.exportJSON`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#exportjson), then resizes it to always fit within the imported view bounds/size.

Comment: I dont see the `pop` method in the return type of importJSON. `importJSON` returns a type `Item` which doesn't seem to have a `pop` definition

Comment: But thanks for suggesting `fitBounds`, it did work for me as follows:
`canvasObj.backgroundLayer.fitBounds(canvasObj.project.view.bounds)`
Here, I have stored the different layers in a `canvasObj`

Comment: @Noober It depends on what you import, in my case I imported an `Array`, hence got back an Array that got the `Layer` as the first item, which I had to `array.pop` out first.